# how to extract string with any operator between?

Tags: regex, perl

I have an array contain `@arr = { "a=b", "a>b", "a<b", "a!=b", "a-b" }`. What is the best way to get a and b with any operator between. I can extract by

```
for($i=0; $i<=$#arr; $i++){
   $str = $arr[$i];
   if($str =~ m/^(.*?)(\s*=\s*)(.*)(;)/g){
         my $d = $1;
         my $e = $3;
   }
```

Follow by all if statement with the possible operator like `"!=", "<"` etc. But this will make my code look messy. Any better solution for this?

Comment: Can i know who down vote this question and the reason? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A very simple regex might be

```
/^(\w+)\s*(\W+)\s*(\w+)$/
```

Or you enumerate possible operators

```
   /^(\w+)\s*(=|!=|<|>|<=|>=|\+|-|\*|\/|==)\s*(\w+)$/
```

It depends whether the input can be trusted or not. If not, you might have to be more meticulous w.r.t. the identifiers, too. Here's a simpler loop, and no need to use m//g(lobal). Not sure about the semicolon - omitted it.

```
my @arr = ( "a=b", "a>b", "a<b", "a!=b", "a-b" );
for my $str (@arr){
    if($str =~ /^(\w+)\s*(=|!=|<|>|<=|>=|\+|-|\*|\/|==)\s*(\w+)$/ ){
         my $d = $1;
         my $e = $3;
         print "d=$d e=$e\n";
    }
}
```

**Later** If you enumerate the operators, you can also add word symbols:

```
if($str =~ /^(\w+)\s*(=|!=|<|>|<=|>=|\+|-|\*|\/|==|x?or|and)\s*(\w+)$/ ){
    ...
```

Comment: Thank it work! One more question if my  '@arr = ( "a and b", "a or b", "a nor b" )'. Can i also done by using one comment?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this one liner

```
perl -e '@a = ("a=b","a>b","a<b","a!=b","a-b"); for $l (@a) { $l =~ s/(.).*(.)/$1/; print "$1$2\n"};'
```

The key thing is the greedy match ie "(.*)" between the two single character matches ie "(.)". To really make sure that you start at the start and end of the strings you could use this

```
perl -e '@a = ("a=b","a>b","a<b","a!=b","a-b"); for $l (@a) { $l =~ s/^(.).*(.)$/$1/; print "$1$2\n"};'
```

A complete working example that demonstrates the whole thing would be

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @expressions = ("a=b","a>b","a<b","a!=b","a-b"); 
for my $exp (@expressions) { 
  $exp =~ s/^(.).*(.)$/$1$2/; 
  print "$1$2 is the same as $exp\n";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if there always 'a' and 'b' at the beginning and the end you could try:

```
my $str =  'a<b';
my( $op ) = $str =~ /^a(.*)b$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a well thought out answer. Will reconsider the problem.